# Change dockerized Django default app from git ignored .env

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, tinymce, django-flatpages

I need to modify the default `flatpages` app which is in django.contrib and `tinymce` in site-packages. Both in gitignored env directory installed from requirements.txt when Docker is starting. How it should be properly done?

[image]

Dockerfile;

[image]

I've tried to pull it out, change imports (a mess) but soon realized it does not make sense as Django is installed from the Docker image..

Comment: Change location of those dirs, update settings.py file and in apps.py file inside each project the variable 'name'

Comment: if you have removed the packages from requirements.txt, then rebuild the image again

Comment: Thank you for your help but I ended up with "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application '*****.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module." after changing location and all imports..